# How to save a file from an HTTP URL and put it into byte [ ]?

Tags: java, file, http, url

I get to know there are many ways like JAVA NIO, HTTP URL Connection, etc. Which is fastest way if File size is around 20MB - 1GB?

Comment: Surely, if you know about them you can just try them out yourself?

Comment: Refer this:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java


This may help you.